# Outsourcing web content versus maintaining local content

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prismic.io

I am developing a full web application...

I am considering using prismic.io to outsource some web content which I will query through graphQL. But I would store personal information about users in a local instance of mongoDB.

**Whats the long term benefit? If I can just store all of the content myself through an instance of mongodb which holds it all for me**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is mostly my opinion,** if you're a developer working alone or just with other developers, and are only looking for a place to store data, then you're probably better off not using a CMS. One of a CMSs main purposes is to extend the ability to significantly modify an application to non-technical individuals. For example, building a website for a local restaurant, and wanting to allow them to change their menu, without you having to build out a UI to enable it. With a CMS they'd be able to easily change the text and other content on their platform, whereas interacting with a mongo backend might be a bit less straightforward for them. For a more industrial example, say you have a marketing team, who need to run A/B tests to determine the optimal content for a site, they can perform their tests, and have their changes reflect into a template you set up, without them (and you if you set it up cleverly) having to write any extra code. There are more advantages and disadvantages to using a CMS, but I think accessibility is the main reason reason to consider one, especially long-term.